# How to update Shopping Cart Total properly in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, performance, shopping-cart

I am looking for some Javascript that will:

- Update Cart Total on products selected (drop-down menu) and quantities entered

(*Security will be handled by back-end PHP. I have attempted this over the last three days but apparently my code was so bad I feel ashamed to repost it here again)

---

My Thinking:
 - Create a cart object
 - Make a function that recalculates the total on any changes that occur
(I can not think of anything else this would require given the javascript will just be passing this over to a PHP script to check anyway)

Does anyone know of some javascript that does the job I seek? Is my thinking correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Below is sample shopping cart javascript object built using revealing module pattern.

```
var shoppingCart = function () {
        var obj = {}, items = [];

        obj.AddItem = function (itemNo, quantity, price) {
            var item = {};
            item.itemNo = itemNo;
            item.quantity = quantity;
            item.price = price;
            items.push(item)
        };

        obj.GetAllItems = function () {
            return items;
        };

        obj.GetItemByNo = function (item) {
            for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
                if (items[i].itemNo === item)
                    return item[i];
            }
            return null;
        };

        obj.CalculateTotal = function () {
            var total = 0;
            for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
                total = total + (items[i].quantity * items[i].price);
            }
            return total;
        };

        return obj;
    };
    var cart = new shoppingCart();
```

Add items using AddItem method, include additional properties that are useful in the UI.

```
shoppingcart.AddItem(2,4,2.4);
```

Gets list of items in the shopping cart

```
var items =  shoppingcart.GetAllItems();
```

Calculates total price of items in shopping cart

```
var total = shoppingcart.CalculateTotal();
```

Please note that I have typed this code in here, so might contain typo's and also I recommend having data type validations for price and quantity as numerics before adding item.

Comment: Impressive Thanks. I think I was getting mixed up in learning Javascript I was just using the first things I came accross rather than thinking pseudo first. I want to expand this to incorporate discount amounts (e.g. 5+ 5% off etc..) and if my thinking is correct I will create a new funtion that handles this before 'AddItem' is called.

Comment: It depends on requirement, if discount can be applied to individual item, you can add another property "discount" to item object. So, consider quantity*(price - (%discount*price)) for total price. If you wish to apply discount to totalAmount, consider having other Method which takes discount% as input and apply to TotalAmount.

Comment: I prefer price calculation on the fly by storing discount% in separate property instead of applying it to price before adding the item.

Comment: If the discount was based on quantity barriers (like 5+ you get 5% off, 10+ you get 7% off) would you then add "discount" to the item object as an array? Or would it be better to copy the "shoppingcart" object and create a product object and when I add an item it gets this information from the "item" object in the new "product" object?

Comment: How would it be best to show you my alterations? In my original question or in a 'add comment' or as answering my own question?

Comment: You should've answered with your alterations, to receive feedback from others incase if you'd any problems.

Comment: I didn't know you could build an object using the "=" sign to assign property values.`var item = { itemNo = itemNo, quantity = quantity, price = price };`  I thought you had to use colon ":" in key/value pairs in an object literal. `var item = { itemNo : itemNo, quantity : quantity, price : price };`

Comment: I know I'm a few years late but this JavaScript code won't work, you simply can't have private variables inside object literal like that.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't review this thread again. Check the updated code.

Comment: this wont work with decimal values though,.